# pygame issue with placing the image on screen

Tags: python, image, pygame, position, coordinates

Im doing a book course where I have to place an image of alien ship in the top left corner. I followed the guidance used the same code but my image is placed too low. I can not figure out what is the source of the problem , I'm using transparent png image. Here is the code I have for Alien , Settings and main classes.Many thanks for assistance.

**Alien class:**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting position."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Images/alien.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the alien at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**Settings class:**

```
class Settings():

    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        #Ship setting
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

        # Bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed_factor =1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60 ,60, 60
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
```

**main class:**

```
from settings import Settings
import pygame
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
from pygame.sprite import Group

import game_functions as gf



def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    # Make a ship
    ship = Ship( ai_settings, screen)
    # Make a group to store bullets in.
    bullets = Group()
    # Make an alien.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)


run_game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the coordinates of the `Alien` sprite on the top left corner, you should use :

```
self.rect.x = 0
self.rect.y = 0
```

Comment: PRMoureu thank you for your solution it worked indeed !! Have good week mate !